# I used arrow operator to print out the variables values of my object and i get some random values as output

Tags: c++, pointers

I tried printing the values of object a of structure node and i'm getting random values as output instead what is assigned in the constructor,the member function works perfectly fine.I also tried assigning the value of the operator like a->right_node=&var and on running the code i get a error message saying the .exe file is not working

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int right_node;
    int left_node;
    int parent_node;

    node(){
        right_node=5;
        left_node=5;
        parent_node=5;
    }

    void func()
    {
        cout<<"Hello World?";
    }
};

int main()
{
    node *a;
    a->func();
    cout<<endl<<a->left_node<<":"<<a->parent_node<<":"<<a->right_node;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The variable `a` is used before it is initialized to point to the memory address of a pre-allocated `node` object.

Comment: @goodvibration if that's the case then why is the member function working?

Comment: The function resides in the code section of your program, so there's no reason for it not to work. However, when you call it with `a`, you are passing to an invalid `node` object address (every member function takes the address of the calling object as its first input argument).

Comment: @user173379 _"... then why is the member function working?"_ Well, _undefined behaviour_ is undefined. No guarantees for anything.

Comment: The title of this question should be "I used arrow operator to print out the variables values of my uninitialized object and I get some undefined behavior" ... C++ is not a nanny-language.  C++ gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.  Turn on your compiler warnings, so you have a fighting chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a pointer to a `node`, but you didn't create a `node` for it to point to.  Dereferencing such an invalid pointer leads to undefined behavior.

You need to create a `node` for `a` to point to.  Either an object with automatic lifetime:

```
int main()
{
    node n;
    node *a = &n;
    a->func();
    std::cout << '\n' << a->left_node << ':' << a->parent_node << ':' << a->right_node;
}
```

Or an object with dynamic lifetime:

```
int main()
{
    node *a = new node;
    a->func();
    std::cout << '\n' << a->left_node << ':' << a->parent_node << ':' << a->right_node;
}
```

Though in the former case you probably don't need a pointer at all, and in the latter case you should use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` to ensure the `node` object gets freed correctly.